# Country drop down change based on geoIp location on cart page

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, geoip

When any guest user **comes at cart page** I want to change the country drop-down based on guest geoIp location.

Here I am adding the actual picture.

[image]

Comment: write more, if you tried something add that too.

Comment: @SohelRana I have updated my queston.

Comment: @ManishGoswami specify your requirement into detail, what you want to do here?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have updated my answer .

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or just ask some question to get solution and code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to using a plugin that overwrites country list with your specific country list. I have used hard-coded country here, you need to add your logic here.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="sr_country_list"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Cart/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    ) {
        $selectedCountry = 'GB';
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {

            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries']['country_id'] as &$country) {
                if ($country['value'] == $selectedCountry) {
                    $country['is_default'] = 1;
                } else {
                    if (isset($country['is_default'])) {
                        unset($country['is_default']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']['address-fieldsets'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']['address-fieldsets']['children']['country_id']['value'] = $selectedCountry;
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-estimation': {
                'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/mixin/shipping-estimation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/shipping-estimation-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/estimate-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'mage/validation'
], function (
    $,
    Component,
    selectShippingAddress,
    addressConverter,
    estimateService,
    checkoutData,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    registry,
    quote,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    shippingService,
    customer
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    return;
                }

                registry.async('checkoutProvider')(function (checkoutProvider) {
                    var address, estimatedAddress;

                    shippingService.isLoading(false);

                    checkoutDataResolver.resolveEstimationAddress();
                    address = quote.isVirtual() ? quote.billingAddress() : quote.shippingAddress();

                    if (!address && quote.isVirtual()) {
                        address = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(
                            checkoutData.getSelectedBillingAddress()
                        );
                    }
                    var selectedCountry = '';
                    $.each(checkoutProvider.dictionaries.country_id, function(index, item) {
                        if (item.is_default != undefined) {
                            selectedCountry = item.value;
                        }
                    });
                    if (address) {
                        estimatedAddress = address.isEditable() ?
                            addressConverter.quoteAddressToFormAddressData(address) :
                            {
                                // only the following fields must be used by estimation form data provider
                                'country_id': address.countryId,
                                region: address.region,
                                'region_id': address.regionId,
                                postcode: address.postcode
                            };

                        if (estimatedAddress.firstname == undefined && selectedCountry) {
                            estimatedAddress.country_id = selectedCountry;
                        }

                        checkoutProvider.set(
                            'shippingAddress',
                            $.extend({}, checkoutProvider.get('shippingAddress'), estimatedAddress)
                        );
                    }

                    if (!quote.isVirtual()) {
                        checkoutProvider.on('shippingAddress', function (shippingAddressData) {
                            checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData(shippingAddressData);
                        });
                    } else {
                        checkoutProvider.on('shippingAddress', function (shippingAddressData) {
                            checkoutData.setBillingAddressFromData(shippingAddressData);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Sohel Rana Its working !!!

Comment: If customer is logged in then it over write customer country.I check is Customers logged in condition but getting js error.

Comment: How can I disable this functionality if customer is logged in.

Comment: I have updated js file. check now

Comment: I don't know why are you answer this question??

Comment: It is working perfectly now thanks again @Sohel Rana !