# Magento 2 plugin not getting called on checkout for shipping

Tags: magento2, plugin, shipping-address, after-plugin

I am trying to preselect the shipping country based on the user's country code.

I have the code already needed to get the country code which is in my model.

I have tried using the code in accepted answer to this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274226/country-drop-down-change-based-on-geoip-location-on-cart-page). It uses an `after` plugin but I can't get it to work. It still defaults to United States even though I 'm telling it to use use GB.

I have tried logging out in the plugin but get nothing in the logs so I don't think the plugin is getting called.

Here is the code:

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="asg_country_list"
                type="Asg\GeoIp\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php

namespace Asg\GeoIp\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    public function beforeProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    ) {
        $path = '/var/www/magento.local/var/log/test.log';

        file_put_contents($path, 'this is a test');
    }

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    ) {
        $selectedCountry = 'GB';

        $this->_logger->info($selectedCountry);

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {

            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries']['country_id'] as &$country) {
                if ($country['value'] == $selectedCountry) {
                    $country['is_default'] = 1;
                } else {
                    if (isset($country['is_default'])) {
                        unset($country['is_default']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']['address-fieldsets'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']['address-fieldsets']['children']['country_id']['value'] = $selectedCountry;
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

I'm using Magento 2.3.4. Could the plugin be calling the wrong module since the original question was Magento 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

tried the plugin code that you have and confirmed that it works with 2.3.x. Both `beforeProcess` and `afterProcess` methods have been called.

`check your logs (debug.log, exception.log and system.log)`...if its a development environment, then `enable the developer mode, which explicitly displays an error` , if an error has been thrown.

In your Plugin Class `Asg\GeoIp\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor` i can see inside the `afterProcess` method you have used `_logger` variable which calls the logging method info, whereas i dont see a constructor where the `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` is injected and initialized.

```
$this->_logger->info($selectedCountry);
```

try this plugin class

```
<?php

namespace Asg\GeoIp\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Cart;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     *
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger ?:
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
    }

    /**
     * Process js Layout of block
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor $layoutProcessor
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return void | null
     *
     */
    public function beforeProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor $layoutProcessor, $jsLayout)
    {
        
        $path = '/var/www/magento.local/var/log/test.log';
        file_put_contents($path,'this is a test');
//        return null;
    }
    
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    ) {
        $selectedCountry = 'GB';

        $this->logger->info('$selectedCountry : '.$selectedCountry);

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {

            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries']['country_id'] as &$country) {
                if ($country['value'] == $selectedCountry) {
                    $country['is_default'] = 1;
                } else {
                    if (isset($country['is_default'])) {
                        unset($country['is_default']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']['address-fieldsets'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']['address-fieldsets']['children']['country_id']['value'] = $selectedCountry;
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Haijerome. I could see the log file being written to on a live dev server but that server it really slow and I can't view the checkout page properly (nothing to do with code, just rendering too slow). I also tried it on a local server (vagrant) but the log is not written to. I know that the plugin is now getting called but can you confirm that the shipping option is getting set? I still can't get that to default to the option set in the plugin